# Does MySQL caching results of custom functions?

Tags: mysql

I have following custom function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TIME_DIFFERENCE(
    ts INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(16)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE result VARCHAR(16);
    SELECT (CASE WHEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP() < ts THEN CONCAT_WS(' ', (CASE WHEN days > 0 THEN CONCAT(days, 'd') END), (CASE WHEN hours > 0 THEN CONCAT(hours, 'h') END), (CASE WHEN minutes > 0 THEN CONCAT(hours, 'm') END))
        WHEN seconds BETWEEN 1 AND 59 THEN 'SOON'
        ELSE 'LIVE' END) INTO result
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            @diff:=ts - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),
            CAST(@days := IF(@diff / 86400 >= 1, floor(@diff / 86400), 0) AS SIGNED) as days,
            CAST(@hours := IF(@diff / 3600 >= 1, floor((@diff:=@diff-@days*86400) / 3600),0) AS SIGNED) as hours,
            CAST(@minutes := IF(@diff / 60 >= 1, floor((@diff:=@diff-@hours*3600) / 60),0) AS SIGNED) as minutes,
            CAST(@diff - @minutes * 60 AS SIGNED) as seconds
    ) AS _;
    RETURN result;
END;
```

When I use this function at different times I get the same result. How to disable caching for calculating value of function?

Comment: *When I use this function at different times I get the same result.* The function is deterministic and must give the same result until data is changed (and changing transaction committed).

Comment: PS. Why you do not use SEC_TO_TIME function and extract time components with expressions and variables?

Comment: @Akina I calculate difference between timestamp (with date) which is stored in INT and current unix timestamp. How to apply SEC_TO_TIME in this case?

Comment: Difference is calculated in second or millisecond. Function converts seconds to TIME datatype (`'hh:mm:ss'`, up to ~1 month). See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time